# How can I make Visual Studio automatically attach its debugger to both a web application and web service?

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, debugging, web-applications

I'm working on a Visual Studio project. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. The project has an ASP.NET application project and a separate ASMX web service project. The web application project is set as the start-up project.

When I tell Visual Studio to start debugging, it correctly starts both the web application and web service. However, it only attaches the debugger to the web application and not the web service. This problem seems to occur regardless of which web server I use for either project (IIS, IIS Express, Visual Studio Development Web Server).

In order to debug both simultaneously, I need to manually attach the debugger to the web service during the debugging session.

How can I make Visual Studio automatically attach to both projects when I tell it start debugging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found that this works if I set both the web service and application to start-up projects. Do this by right-clicking the solution file and choosing something like *Set Start-up Projects...*.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to open two instances of Visual Studio and debug the projects separately, however it is pretty much the same inconvenience as attaching the debugger manualy.

By the way, do you have ASP.NET debugger allowed in both projects (project properties > web tab > debuggers section)?

Comment: Yes; I have the ASP.NET debugger enabled in both projects.